# Angularjs .success{} with php generated image

Tags: php, angularjs

i am trying to open up the result of `guestprint.php` (generates image with inputs) with success function.

Controller.js:

```
$scope.guestPrint = function() {

 $http({
   url: request_server + 'guestprint.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: $scope.admin,
   headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }

 }).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                     ---???---
 });

}
```

guestprint.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("content-type: application/json");

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//...
//..database and authorisation stuff
//...

if($result['result'] == 1 && $user_role == 1 ) {
    $ModelCertificate=new ModelCertificate();
    echo json_encode($ModelCertificate->guestIDCard($data));
}
//...
```

- guestIDCard() starts with `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`
- If i try to save image, it's works. (`imagejpeg($img,
  "./save/here/or/here");`) But i am trying to bring it to browser
  without saving it

**So how can i redirect myself to guestprint.php when it successfully creates image with $data i got from forms?**

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to convert the image you have on the server to a base64 string.

```
$data = file_get_contents(<PATH TO IMG>);
$base64 = 'data:image/<IMAGE EXTENSION (png, jpg, etc..)>;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Send that base64 string back to the front-end.

Once you have it on the front-end you can use that base64 string as the src of an img.

```
<img ng-src="{{base64img}}">
```

p.s.: .success() and .error() are deprecated (1.4+) and completely removed in (1.6+). I recommend using .then(success, error)

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of it and made it with saving image.

---

Controller.js:

```
$scope.guestPrint = function() {
    $http({
        url: request_server + 'guestprint.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $scope.admin, //dont mind this
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
       $http({
        url: request_server + 'guestdw.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { user: $rootScope.user }, //dont mind this
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' //!important
        }
        }).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {

        var blob = new Blob([response], {
            type: "image/jpeg"
        });
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
        });
    });
}
```

guestdw.php:

```
$yourfile = "./path/to/file.jpeg";
    $file_name = basename($yourfile);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($yourfile));
    readfile($yourfile);
```